# Frameworks to Auto-testing a Webapp

Tags: javascript, python, testing, frameworks, automated-tests

I´m just getting into a new job, and my mission is to search and implement a framework to test a web app in JS. 
I don´t know a lot about those frameworks but I found those:

- Jest
- Mocha
- Cypress
- Selenium

Can you suggest to me if are them good?

PS: Are there any frameworks which use Python to automate the testing? 
Because I like python it´s most familiar to me than JS.

Thanks!

Comment: Recommendations for frameworks are explicitly off-topic per the [help].

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to very new automation framework gauge, It is available with various languages, here you go for python: [gauge-python](https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-python/releases)

I am using it with `javascript` and really enjoying it . :)